# Value relation widget, data is saved as Value Column instead of the Key column

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm pretty shocked that I can't add a Key column apart of a Value column in my QGIS relation attribute table. I use as Value relation column field with the code follow by the latin name of plant species and for column only the code (6 letters) (image 1,2). In Key column I want the code in the assigned column to show instead of the entire name. But the name displayed both in the form list and in the attribute table is the Column value, even if my settings are right (the key is the one enter in attribute table and the column is the one seen in the form) (image3,4). Also, I noticed that my field "no_colonie" with default expression involving my species field show correctly the code value only. Please help me find what's wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]